Deploying python function apps to azure
I am trying to make my first python function app. The app is just a simple app that creates a blob file. The code runs locally. However when I deploy to Azure I dont see the function app.

If I remove this, then it works:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

Full code:
import logging
import datetime
import azure.functions as func

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

app = func.FunctionApp()
    
@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=False, use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
     
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

Configuration in azure:
[
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "xx-6dd2-xx-9ab8-xx",
    "slotSetting": true
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "InstrumentationKey=xx;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=xxx",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "BUILD_FLAGS",
    "value": "UseExpressBuild",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname",
    "value": "stsxxxondev",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "python",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "XDG_CACHE_HOME",
    "value": "/tmp/.cache",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]


Are you getting any specific error?

"There is an error" in the azure portal > What error are you getting?

Nopes, I should have clarified that better - sorry. I updated post. I just not see the function. Its if I have the imports it happens. Even before code is running: from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

I have deployed your code and able to see the function trigger in Portal.

Did you deploy it with uncommenting the blob storage code?

yes, you can check the code in the image

I see. What do you think can cause this at my end? I guess you just right click in visual studio code and choose Deploy to azure?

Right, you can try deploying using command func azure functionapp publish <functionappname>

Check the answer below.

I have created a Python Azure function App and deployed your function code. Able to sync the timer trigger in portal.
function_app.py:
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient

app = func.FunctionApp()

def upload_blob_data(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name: str):

     time_now  = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S') 
     blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=f"{time_now}.txt")
     data = b"Sample data for blob"

     # Upload the blob data - default blob type is BlockBlob    
     blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob")

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=False, use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

     account_url = "https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net"
     credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Create the BlobServiceClient object
     blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=credential)
     upload_blob_data(blob_service_client, "json")
     logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}


Enable Managed Identity in the function app.

Navigate to Storage Account=>Access Control=>Add Role Assignment, assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the functionapp's managed identity.




Add application setting AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname= <storagename> in the Function app=>settings=>Environment Variables:


Deployment logs:

Portal:

Response:

Blobs in Storage Container:


Thanks highly appreciated. What config do you have on the function app, and did you set any specific permissions on the storage account with the managed identity?

I have assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor Role to the functionapp's managed identity. Try enabling the identity after deploying the function.

I have same permissions and MI enabled. That part also works locally. And I changed main post so it only includes the imports. Its even before accessing any storage acccount it fails. Can it be some kind of python version, og something in the environement settings?

Add AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname= storagename application setting in functionapp's configuration

Check the updated answer.

Checked all of it, copied your code. I noticed my requirements file on the server only contains azure-functions. Do you have anything in your requirements file?

I have azure-functions, azure-identity, azure-storage-blob image. Did you try deploying using command func azure functionapp publish <functionappname>?

I justed used the plugin in VS Code. I will try your way, and get back with the result.

Still same. My requirements is empty. Have you updated your manually? I got following response "Done in 44 sec(s).
Writing the artifacts to a Zip file
Running post deployment command(s)...
Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
PS C:\Development\DnA\PythonSample>"

This is my wwroot: pycache/  11/25/2024 18:18:51 +00:00
function_app.py 389 11/25/2024 19:15:38 +00:00
host.json 288 11/25/2024 19:11:32 +00:00
requirements.txt 200 11/25/2024 19:11:34 +00:00

WhichApp service plan are you using for function app?

Pravallika KV thanks alot. You have been so helpfull highly appreciated. After adding the same as you in requirements it worked! Thanks again!
